# SPARQL: Binding the result of an aggregate function does not work

Tags: sparql, ontology

Suppose we have the following dataset measuring heart rate observations:

| userId | observation | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| :alice | obs_1_1 | 102 |
| :alice | obs_1_2 | 105 |
| :alice | obs_1_3 | 97 |
| :bob | obs_2_1 | 78 |
| :bob | obs_2_2 | 86 |
| :bob | obs_2_3 | 84 |

And we want to determine which of the users have an average heart rate of >100.

The following query returns empty values for the `BIND`:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX sosa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/>

SELECT ?user ?result (AVG(?res) AS ?avg_heart_rate) WHERE { 
    ?obs rdf:type sosa:Observation ;
          sosa:hasSimpleResult ?res ;
          sosa:hasFeatureOfInterest ?user .
    BIND (?avg_heart_rate>100 AS ?result) .
} GROUP BY ?user ?result
```

Resultset:

| ?user | ?result | ?avg_heart_reate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| :alice |  | 101.333 |
| :bob |  | 82.667 |

Any idea what I am doing wrong will be highly appreciated!

Comment: that's because the aggregate is evaluated after the inner query is evaluated for obvious reasons. In general to use an aggregate in a graph pattern is to use a subquery. But for your case the way to go is to use `HAVING`

Comment: `PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX sosa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/>

SELECT ?user ?result (AVG(?res) AS ?avg_heart_reate) WHERE { 
    ?obs rdf:type sosa:Observation ;
          sosa:hasSimpleResult ?res ;
          sosa:hasFeatureOfInterest ?user .
} GROUP BY ?user ?result HAVING (?avg_heart_reate > 100)`

Comment: @UninformedUser many thanks for this, `HAVING` is indeed the way to go! However, I would prefer to have true/false in the resultset (as shown in the table above). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Responding to my previous comment, in order to have true/false in the results as well, we need an inner query as @UninformedUser suggested: `PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX sosa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/>

SELECT ?user ?avg_heart_reate ?result WHERE {
    {
        SELECT ?user (AVG(?res) AS ?avg_heart_reate) WHERE { 
            ?obs rdf:type sosa:Observation ;
                  sosa:hasSimpleResult ?res ;
                  sosa:hasFeatureOfInterest ?user .
        } GROUP BY ?user
    }
    BIND (?avg_heart_reate>100 AS ?result) .
}`

Comment: ah, I didn't recognize that you want to keep track of whether it made it above the threshold or not. Yeah, in that case you can just wrap it into a sub-`SELECT`. You shouldn't group by `result` though

Comment: But even more convenient, you could reuse the aggregated variable in the projection part and avoid the subquery: `PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX sosa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/>


SELECT ?user (AVG(?res) AS ?avg_heart_reate) (?avg_heart_reate > 100 as ?result) WHERE { 
    ?obs rdf:type sosa:Observation ;
          sosa:hasSimpleResult ?res ;
          sosa:hasFeatureOfInterest ?user .
} GROUP BY ?user`

Comment: Oh nice! That's a really elegant way to solve this! Many thanks!